# How session works in coldfusion?

Tags: session, coldfusion

I have some doubts regarding the session and client management in coldfusion.

> Note: The behavior is as follows when CFID and CFTOKEN are provided in the URL: If session exists, the CFID and CFTOKEN from the URL are ignored. If the session does not exist, CFID and CFTOKEN from the URL are used to validate the session and the session is used if it is valid. If the session is not valid, a new session is created. CFID and CFTOKEN are regenerated.

This is a statement from adobe ColdFusion [online documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/managing-the-client-state.html). Below are my questions

1. How ColdFusion checks if the session exists without the help of CFID and CFTOKEN as in the first sentence?
2. Suppose we are using ColdFusion session management, if the CFTOKEN and CFID doesn't change after login can we hijack the session?

Comment: Be sure to read about the recommendations regarding ColdFusion sessions and cookies in the [lock down guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/coldfusion-2016-lockdown-guide.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion checks for a valid session by checking if CFID and CFTOKEN exist in the cookies scope. If the CFID and CFTOKEN cookies exist, it will use the cookie values to try and validate the session. If it can't validate the session using the cookie values, it will use the URL values to try and validate the session.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the documentations says this case when cookies disabled. So _If session exists, the CFID and CFTOKEN from the URL are ignored._ this line makes me confuse. If there is no cookies how ColdFusion checks if the session exists?

Comment: ACF uses CFID/TOKEN, or alternately JSESSIONID ( JEE Sessions through CF Admin setting) to maintain session state. Without those variables, ACF can't maintain session state. Do you have a link to the specific docs that are confusing you?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/managing-the-client-state.html - In this "Using client and session variables without cookies" this section

Comment: The language isn't clear because of where they placed it. What it should say is: if cookies are enabled and the session exists, the CFID and CFTOKEN on the URL will be ignored. That is the expected behavior of ACF.

Answer (score 1):

[Using client and session variables without cookies](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cbf)

It's possible for users to disable cookies in their browsers. In this case, ColdFusion cannot maintain the client state automatically. You can use client or session variables without using cookies, by passing the client identification information between application pages. However, this technique has significant limitations, as follows:

1. Client variables are effectively the same as session variables, except that they leave unusable data in the client data store.
   Because the client’s system does not retain any identification information, the next time the user logs on, ColdFusion cannot identify the user with the previous client and must create a new client ID for the user. Any information about the user from a previous session is not available, but remains in client data storage until ColdFusion deletes it. If you clear the Purge Data for Clients that Remain Unvisited option in the ColdFusion Administrator, ColdFusion never deletes this data.
   Therefore, do not use client variables, if you allow users to disable cookies. To retain client information without cookies, require users to login with a unique ID. You can then save user-specific information in a database with the user’s ID as a key.
2. ColdFusion creates a new session each time the user requests a page directly in the browser, because the new request contains no state information to indicate the session or client.

Note: You can prevent ColdFusion from sending client information to the browser as cookies by setting This.setClientCookies variable in Application.cfc or the setClientCookies attribute of the cfapplication tag to No.

To use ColdFusion session variables without using cookies, each page must pass the CFID and CFToken values to any page that it calls as part of the request URL. If a page contains any HTML hrefa= links, cflocation tags, form tags, or cfform tags the tags must pass the CFID and CFToken values in the tag URL. To use J2EE session management, pass the jsessionid value in page requests. To use ColdFusion client variables and J2EE session variables, pass the CFID, CFToken, and jsessionid values in URLs.

Note: The behavior is as follows when CFID and CFTOKEN are provided in the URL: If session exists, the CFID and CFTOKEN from the URL are ignored. If the session does not exist, CFID and CFTOKEN from the URL are used to validate the session and the session is used if it is valid. If the session is not valid, a new session is created. CFID and CFTOKEN are regenerated.

ColdFusion provides the URLSessionFormat function, which does the following:

If the client does not accept cookies, automatically appends all required client identification information to a URL.

If the client accepts cookies, does not append the information.
The URLSessionFormat function automatically determines which identifiers are required, and sends only the required information. It also provides a more secure and robust method for supporting client identification than manually encoding the information in each URL, because it only sends the information that is required, when it is required, and it is easier to code.

To use the URLSessionFormat function, enclose the request URL in the function. For example, the following cfform tag posts a request to another page and sends the client identification, if necessary:

```
<cfform method="Post" action="#URLSessionFormat("MyActionPage.cfm")#>
```

If you use the same page URL in multiple URLSessionFormat functions, you can gain a small performance improvement and simplify your code if you assign the formatted page URL to a variable, for example:

```
<cfset myEncodedURL=URLSessionFormat(MyActionPage.cfm)> 
<cfform method="Post" action="#myEncodedURL#">
```

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence of this answer.  While it's possible for people to disable cookies, I suspect that it happens less often than one would think.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree with that.